# Exceeding the 500 peer limit in chrome (Cannot create so many PeerConnections)

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

Im working on a DDoS application to do some testing, and require more than 500 peer connections to be created. I did some digging into related questions, but it seems like no matter what I do, or what state I clear, I cannot exceed the 500 peer limit.

In short i'm trying to clear the peer on a 401:

```
function iceCandidateError(e, pc) {
    console.log(e.errorCode);
    if (e.errorCode == 401) {
        pc.close();
        pc = null;
    }
}

async function makeCall(config, requestCount) {
    const offerOptions = { offerToReceiveAudio: 1 };
    console.log(
        `Creating new PeerConnection with config=${JSON.stringify(config)}`
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < requestCount; i++) {
        let pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
        pc.onicecandidateerror = (event) => iceCandidateError(event, pc);
        const desc = await pc.createOffer(offerOptions);
        await pc.setLocalDescription(desc);
    }
}
```

Do I need to do something funky here?

Looking at `chrome://webrtc-internals/`, I can see tons of peer connections opened, but none are removed - they just persist there. I figured `pc.close()` would indeed close it.

Comment: see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825576 -- *something* is holding on and stopping garbage collection. Error logging in the console was a recent culprit

Comment: Philipp - I owe you a few coffees.